# react native windows app not connecting to localhost

Tags: node.js, express, react-native-windows

I have been working on react-native for windows app the thing is I created a localhost in node.js using express and made api calls from the windows app both the server and app were working fine on my device even after when i created appx bundle file and installed it on my computer then i shared the appx bundle file and my localserver file with my friend and it was causing problem there. Localhost was working fine i could make requests via postman but was not able to do so via the app it gives

> Error : Network Error

. I am looking for some help if anyone have any idea about what could be going on.

Note that everything works fine on my development device

Comment: Define "not able" please.

Comment: I dont get any response it stops after call timeout

Comment: Actually i would like to add if it helps understanding the issue that when server is running i get this 503 server not available error almost after six seconds but when it is really down i get it in less than a second.